# SQL if row not present 0 else column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below query , whenever there is no row present I need to minus 0 from quantity, i tried with **is null** and **COALESCE** but this wont work if the resulted row is not present. How can I achieve it?

```
SELECT 
    A.Quantity - ISNULL((CASE WHEN B.QuantityOrdered > 0 
                                THEN B.QuantityOrdered
                                ELSE 0 END), 0) AS QTY
FROM 
    TABLE1 A 
LEFT JOIN 
    Item ON ITEM.ID = A.ItemId 
LEFT JOIN 
    [TABLE2] B ON ITEM.ID = B.ITEMID
WHERE 
    (Item.ItemLookupCode + '-' + A.LotNumber) = '200001-4H71582A';
```

`select *  FROM TABLE2 WHERE ItemLookupCode='200001-4H71582A'` is an empty result sometimes, if there is no value I need to assign 0.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the row is not present because the `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.  This can be fixed by moving the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT (A.Quantity -
        (CASE WHEN B.QuantityOrdered > 0 THEN B.QuantityOrdered ELSE 0 END)
       ) AS QTY
FROM TABLE1 A LEFT JOIN
     Item i
     ON i.ID = A.ItemId AND
        (i.ItemLookupCode + '-' + A.LotNumber) = '200001-4H71582A' LEFT JOIN
     [TABLE2] B
     ON i.ID = B.ITEMID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to filter the result set based on the item look up code,and update the quantity , use the below query :

```
SELECT A.Quantity - (CASE WHEN ISNULL(B.QuantityOrdered,0) > 0 
                            THEN B.QuantityOrdered
                            ELSE 0 END) AS QTY 
FROM TABLE1 A 
 LEFT JOIN Item ON ITEM.ID = A.ItemId 
 LEFT JOIN [TABLE2] B ON ITEM.ID = B.ITEMID
WHERE (ISNULL(Item.ItemLookupCode,'') + '-' + A.LotNumber) = '200001-4H71582A';
```

Make sure the 'itemlookupcode' that you are working is there in the table ITEM.

Comment: The problem is most of the time the itemlookupcode we  search won't be available in the database. If the itemlookupcode referred is not present I need to assign 0 as  CASE result.

Comment: Could you please provide some more inputs.. do you want the result set against all the records in table 1 or specific to any lot number in table 1?